# Concatenating php source code files for performance

Tags: php, performance

I have a php application that has around 1,200 files/classes in it that is also working with a vendor directory containing 13,000 files in it.

The reason I'm asking is that our web host started to complain about too many read operations being performed by us. I think it could be caused by our entire app + libs directory being loaded for each request.

I'm just curious if concatenating entire application into one big file could help with performance and reduce the number of read operations? Or it also harm performance?

Does anybody have experience with this?
Is that a thing to investigate?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The are other options like chaching mechanics that can cache scripts. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11355429/4916265

Comment: About concateing all: There is no information about the `application` you use, so its hard to say something. But: classes/namespaced classes can always be concated if declared in the right way.

Comment: your app really opens every of the 1300 files on each request??

Comment: @Philipp - good question. I've done some tests using `get_included_files();` in shutdown handler. Usual number was around 100, so seems like they are not opened on each request. This is also what I expected.. that's why I am also confused by our web host complaining. Numbers they provided seemed like all of them would have been accessed in every request.